# Como notificar usuário Web Api com SignalR?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api, signalr

Ao receber um `post` em uma aplicação `Web Api` preciso notificar um determinado cliente que foi inserido um novo registro. Esse usuário vai ver essa notificação em uma aplicação cliente(`javascript`) separada do projeto `Web Api` e vai estar logado utilizando `Identity`.

Como enviar uma notificação com `SignalR` para esse determinado cliente(com base no login `Identity`)?

Comment: Você já montou um Hub pra comunicar o usuário?

Comment: Man, conheçe o Pusher? é um serviço que, digamos assim, terceriza isso pra ti, eu tenho um post sobre ele. O legal é que vc faz a conta no serviço do pusher, cria um canal e um evento, baixa a api deles, e de um lado dispara o evento e do outro, a pagina, registra via javascript o evento, bem bacana.
http://wp.me/p2AWkc-7y

Answer (score 2):

Acho que esta procurando algo como **"AJAX Reverso"**, não encontrei uma definição em português mas vai aqui um link para entender melhor como ele funciona **[prokata.com/reverseajax.html](http://prokata.com/reverseajax.html)**.

Na época utilizei o **[DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)** mas é uma implementação para java, no caso do ASP.NET vi que existe o **[Pokein](http://pokein.com/)** mas parece que não é gratuito, tem um opção de *"Free community edition"* mas não encontrei para donwload.

Mas acredito que exista alguma implementação gratuita por ai, acho que não somos os únicos que já precisou utilizar este recurso antes.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O DWR e bom mas precisa ter aceso no servidor para instalar. Então precisa saber se Carlos pode fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Carlos, considerando que seu Hub esteja implementado no mesmo projeto que o WebApi:

Quando o um usuário (via javascript) conectar no seu Hub, você grava o ConnectionId e UserId do Identity dele em um banco de dados (por exemplo).

Quando acontecer o POST, você pode pegar uma instância do seu Hub e enviar a mensagem para o cliente que quiser.

Para obter uma instância do Hub, faça:

```
var meuHub =  GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TIPO_DO_MEU_HUB>();
```

e para enviar uma mensagem, você faz como se estivesse dentro do Hub, exemplo:

```
meuHub.Clients.Client(ConnectionId_DO_CLIENTE).enviaMensagemParaOCliente("woot");
```

Na hora do POST você verifica qual ConnectionId do cliente destinatário via o UserId dele e manda a mensagem, lembrando que um mesmo UserId pode ter mais de um ConnectionId (multiplos navegadores/dispositivos) -então você provavelmente vai querer notificar todos.

Answer (score 0):

Um servidor nao pode chamar um cliente porque Internet e baseado sobre um sistema de pequenos mesangem: ligaçao, transmiçao, corta ligaçao etc... Entao e o cliente que vai dever chamar o servidor.

O que vc pode fazer e colocar um pedaço de JS no site, com um timer.
Por exemplo cada minutos, a pagina vai chamar o servidor para saber se tem um novo mesagem (veja setTimeout() )

2 opçoes:
1) a pagina chama o servido entao tem um "refresh" da pagina. Muito facil mais no bem "estetico" porque com o sem mensagem no servidor vai ter um "refresh"
2) usar XMLHttpRequest() o que permite um codigo JS de chamar uma outra pagina e receber as informaçoes, sem fazer um "refresh".

Comment: Peter, você está certo ao dizer que apenas um cliente pode iniciar uma conexão mas isso não tem nada a ver com a pergunta. É perfeitamente possível e comum enviar dados em tempo real a partir do servidor para o cliente, sem uma requisição específica (veja socket.io ou signalr, por exemplo)

Comment: E verdade Leo, mas SOMENTE depois da chamada do cliente. Porque para conversar com um cliente o servidor deve ter o IP de cliente. Um servidor tem um IP "fixa" mas não o cliente. Pior, NADA pode demonstrar que se o servidor envia dados durante 10 minutos, o cliente vai continuar a ter o mesmo IP durante os 10 minutos. Hoje, por exemplo, meu rede internet caiu três vezes, cada vez por 2 ou 3 minutos. E a cada vez, o endereço IP atribuído foi diferente.

Comment: Peter, como eu falei: isso não tem nada a ver com a pergunta feita. Problemas de desconexão devem se tratados pelo programador, se ele quer enviar notificaçoes do servidor para o cliente e são bem fáceis de tratar, seja usando uma abstração como o SignalR ou websockets puro. A suas sugestões para a necessidade dele são _extremamente_ ineficientes e ficaria muito preocupado em ver um site profissional as utilizando hoje em dia.

Comment: Isso tem MUITO a ver com a pergunta. Porque se Carlos e sozinho no seu escritório, e que durante todo a seu tempo de programação, ele tem a mesma IP, ele vai ser feliz porque vai funcionar. Mas quando ele vai conectar um segundo computador o que a sua ligação internet vai cair, mesmo 5 segundos e que ele vai receber um novo IP, ele não vai entender porque não funciona mas.

Comment: Peter, dá uma lida de novo na pergunta, ele não está perguntando nada sobre como funciona o protocolo HTTP, provavelmente ele já sabe (já que programa web), bem como o fato comum de ocasional mudança de IP. Ele está só perguntando como enviar uma notificação ao cliente, a partir do servidor, prática simples e bem conhecida atualmente. Sua resposta é ruim para quem cair aqui porque dá a entender que o que ele quer fazer só é possível via poolling ou refresh, o que não só não é verdade como - repito - extremamente ineficiente e deve ser desencorajado.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que vc vai ter um cliente (A) que vai se conectar por exemplo a 14H00. Um outro cliente (B) vai enviar um mensagem no servidor por exemplo a 15H00. O que vc quer fazer e enviar uma informação no cliente A, para informar que tem um novo mensagem.

E impossível ter certeza que isso vai funcionar. Por que?

1) entre a connection do cliente A a 14H00 e o momento o vc vai enviar um mensagem 15H00, o cliente A pode mudar de IP

2) Se o cliente tem 2 computadores, um roteador e um modem, quando o servidor vai salvar o IP, ele não vai salvar o IP do cliente, mas o IP do roteador. Vc pode fazer o test seguinte: coloca no seu site uma pagina que mostra o IP, conecta-se com um computador de seu rede e depois com um outro do mesmo rede e vc vai ver que do ponto de vista do servidor os dois tem o mesmo IP.

Quando criamos um CHAT por exemplo, tem o mesmo problema: mostrar para o  cliente A, os mensagens do cliente B, C etc... 
O SignalR pode ser usado, mas não como vc acha. Vc diz "Como enviar uma notificação com SignalR para esse determinado cliente(com base no login Identity)?" o que significa que vc acha que e o servidor que vai chamar o cliente A.
Não e possível (infelizmente)

De verdade com o SignalR, vc vai determinar o tempo da chamada. E o cliente A que vai dever (por exemplo cada 5 segundos) chamar o servidor. Então, o servidor vai saber quem "chama" e vai dar a resposta certa.

Vc pode dar uma olhada aqui:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-high-frequency-realtime-with-signalr

Vc pode tambem dar uma olhada aqui:
https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR
Na pasta Scripts tem jquery.signalR-2.2.0-pre-140709-b104.js (linhas 694 e seguinte para entender o principio).

Comment: Peter você está errado. No momento em que há a mudança de IP você perde a conexão com o servidor. Se você está usando o SignalR, ele tenta a reconexão e basta você tratar esta reconexão no seu Hub. Não precisa se preocupar com IP, é tudo abstraído pra você - você só precisa gerenciar o ConnectionId que é o "endereço" do cliente p/ quem você quer enviar uma mensagem. O "teste" que você sugere é irrelevante, a internet funciona perfeitamente, mesmo com NAT. O que Carlos está perguntando é perfeitamente possível. E também está errado em dizer que é preciso fazer pooling no signalR.